# How to make it so that when you click on a certain area on the background image, a transition to another site is carried out? HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a background image and I want to click on a certain area to take me to a website, how can I do that?

Comment: Sounds lika i HTML Image Map - Take a look at :https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_images_imagemap.asp

Comment: Is this of any help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54057726/how-to-find-a-right-place-on-a-webpage-to-make-a-click?

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a duplicate of:

[How to make a section of an image a clickable link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18560097/how-to-make-a-section-of-an-image-a-clickable-link)

Here's a quick little example I made based on the answer to that question:

https://jsfiddle.net/hw6L5ye9/

```html
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXgSW.png" width="500" height="300" alt="alttext" usemap="#mapname">

<map name="mapname">
    <area shape="rect" coords="35,230,210,290" href="http://www.example.com" alt="alttext">
</map>
```